# Early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" Ubuntu Does Not Boot

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, macbook, boot-failure, macosx

Just a little info on my computer: I have the early 2011 MacBook Pro 13" with Intel HD 3000 graphics. On my internal HDD, I have OSX and a small partition of Windows 7 that I dual boot with. I have an external HDD that I use for back ups.

I partitioned my external HDD to install Ubuntu 12.04. I partitioned it correctly and ticked the install updates while installing Ubuntu button.

So it installs, downloads and installs all of the updates it thinks it needs. 
Tells me to reboot, so it ejects the live disk, then it reboots.

I installed rEFit, so it boots directly to this screen. I see my OS X, Windows and Ubuntu partitions. I select boot to Ubuntu, it brings up the penguin and then boots directly to Windows. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: OP hasn't signed on in 5+ years. Question is unanswered. 12.04 is EOL. VTC as `not reproducible`.